# Android back button and onResume()

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a "main" activity with a button that starts a second activity using:-

```
var intent = new Intent(Context, typeof(EditFormActivity));
Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

When I tap the phone's "back" button from the second activity, I was surprised to see that the "main" activity's `OnCreateView()` gets called. I was under the impression that only its `OnResume()` method would be called. What am I missing?

(I'm still new to Android so it's probably my misunderstanding of the Activity lifecycle).

**Edit**
I neglected to mention that the events are in a fragment that Resides in the main activity. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: "main" `Activity` was destroyed by the system due to low memory when the `Activity` was in background. That's how `Android` acts. Since it was destroyed, according to [Activity's lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle), it was recreated, so its `onCreate()` was called.

Comment: @Onik that was the only situation I could think of. I'm running it in an emulator with plenty of ram though.

Answer (score 0):

The `onCreateView` is not really part of the Activity Lifeycle. But `onResume()` is.

You must have made a confusion with `onCreate()`.

**EDIT:**

The `onCreateView` of a fragment is called when the activity starts and when it resumes. No, the `onResume()` method won't be the only one called. This happens because when you pause your activity, the fragment is detached from it. So when you resume the activity, the fragment has to be re-attached and this causes the call of onCreateView.

Here's the fragment lifecycle for you to understand how it works:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Method `onCreateView()` is part of fragment's lifecycle, not activity's lifecycle.

Fragment does not need to be destroyed to call `onCreateView()`.

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating) for managing fragment's lifecycle.